# Command in yml file doesn't function standard output

Tags: bash

I have a command line `A` in an `abc.yml` file such like:

```
- #Determine Sum Total Size of Regions in a BED File                                                                                                                                      
    cmd: "{bedtools} genomecov -i {capture} -g {chrsize} -max 1 >{out_dir}{ID}.insert.size"
```

All files in {} have been predefined and the command is equivalent to `B`:

```
/usr/bin/bedtools genomecov -i ./Data/cl1_Freedman_w_capture_targets.bed \
-g ./Code/Roche_QC/data/chormosome_sizes.txt \
-max 1 >./Code/Roche_QC/tmp/AD-S3_S3/AD-S3_S3.insert.size
```

However I was able to run the `B` command in terminal but when I execute the command line in `abc.yml` file, it shows error as:

```
*****ERROR: Unrecognized parameter: >./Code/Roche_QC/tmp/AD-S1_S1/AD-S1_S1.insert.size *****
```

My question is why the standard out command `>` wasn't recognized in command `A`.

Comment: Are you sure it's really being passed to bash?  Sounds like the command was just executed as-is.

Comment: Yes, the `B` was I copied command by executing `abc.yml`

Comment: Additionally, if I remove `>file`, the `abc.yml` will be working.

Comment: Re-read what @FatalError said.  It looks like the arguments to `cmd` are executed directly, rather than being passed to a shell.  This would mean that shell features such as io redirection (`>`, `|`, etc) won't work.  What is processing your yaml file?